# Load default value in text field in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a text field where the user enters a numeric value to be converted from inches to feet.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Is there a way to load a default 0 in the value here or in the java section so that if the radio button is clicked with an empty string it does not load an error?

Comment: something like android:text = "0" ?

Comment: That did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 1st part of the question you can use the following code in Edit text xml:

```
android:text="0"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android:text="your_default_value_goes_here"
```